# set interval is calling the function at strange times

Tags: javascript

I have 5 divs that I want to change the color of when the function is called, however each time the function is called the time given in the set interval seems to decrease.

```
let runways = [runway1, runway2, runway3, runway4, runway5];

const checkRunway = () =>{
    for(let i = 0; i < runways.length; i++){
        if(runways[i].available === true){
            runways[i].available = false
            document.getElementById(`runway${[i]}`).style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            break;
        }
    }
}

const landing = () =>{
    if(selection.value == 'DC35'){
        checkRunway();
        setInterval(function(){
          runways[i].available = true; 
          document.getElementById(`runway${[i]}`).style.backgroundColor = 'green'
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: How/when is `landing` called?

Comment: How are you even able to call the runways[i].available [I] in the landing? or Am i too bad in Javascript?

Comment: I think you may be confusing `setInterval` with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). That said, it really isn't clear what your code is doing, etc. We need a [mcve] here

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the landing function is called using onclick with a button in my html document.

Comment: you are accessing runways as array of objects but all i see is invalid array of strings?

Comment: @BlackXero it's out of context, but I'm pretty sure `runway1` etc are objects defined elsewhere (especially since they have an `available` property)

Comment: @BlackXero I declared i globaly

Answer (score 1):

Your `setInterval` time isn't decreasing, it isn't stopping. You've never told it to stop, so what's most likely happening is that you're duplicating the `setInterval`s each time you call the function, meaning that multiples are running at once time. This would give you the false impression that your current click, causes a reaction, sooner. When in fact, it was a previous `setInterval`, executing.

If you only want it to happen once, say `onclick`, then use `setTimeout` instead.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    runways[i].available = true; 
    document.getElementById(`runway${[i]}`).style.backgroundColor = 'green'
}, 1000);
```